# How to access or get Providerkey after user login using OAuth2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new with the ASP.Net MVC 5 and using built-in identity to build a simple ASP.net website. And I am also new with C#.

I successfully configure my google account for the OAuth2 settings and can successfully login to my google account. The Login info are stored in "ASPNetUserLogins" table.

Now, I wan't to get the "ProviderKey" in order for me to use google API to list my projects in my GCP (google cloud Platform).

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var providerKey = GetProviderkey(User.Identity.GetUserId());

                // do some logic later. 
            }

            return View();
        }

        private string GetProviderkey(string UserID)
        {
            var _userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var user = _userManager.GetLogins(UserID);
            var providerKey = "";

            if (user != null)
            {
                var info = user.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Equals(user));
                providerKey = info.ProviderKey;
            }

            return providerKey;
        }
```

I got and error my variable "info" is null. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

ahh ok.. just solved it. ;)

```
        private string GetProviderkey(string UserID)
        {
            var _userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var user = _userManager.FindById(UserID);
            var providerKey = "";

            if (user != null)
            {
                var info = user.Logins.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserId == UserID);
                providerKey = info.ProviderKey;
            }

            return providerKey;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core `user.Logins` is no longer available. You can however get logins like this:

```
var logins = await _userManager.GetLoginsAsync(user);
foreach (var login in logins)
{
    //login.LoginProvider and login.ProviderKey);
}
```